# C# List Of Orders Made

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to C# and still learning, my apologies if this is a simple question.
When a user orders an item(s), the items are assigned an OrderId which is then related to an Order using this OrderId. Now however I need to link both of these and display them so only the user ordering them can view them(Based on the Username which is stored in Orders Class)

How would I do this in my ViewOrdersController?

Current Classes:
Order

```
[Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
    public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
        public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

OrderDetail

```
 public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Im trying to create a controller that allows the user that has made the order to view his order

Comment: your question is completely vague - can you show your current classes?
also, what's this ViewOrdersController? list that shows items? custom controller?

Comment: show some code what you already tried ?

Comment: Sorry reading back I realize how vague it is, ill edit the main post in one moment

Comment: The problem is I don't even know where to start, I've tried a few things but nothings working so I have no valid code to show

Comment: you should have some kind of authorization for users, then when you know what user requesting the data - you can return corresponding order

Comment: @AndreQueen are you using entity framework?

Comment: Im using asp.net mvc with visual studio 2015

Comment: public string Username { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

```
int orderId = // The orderId you want to use
Items.Where(item => item.OrderId == orderId)
```

This example is done with Linq (the `.Where` function) and expression trees with lambdas (the `=>`). hope this helps. I would recommend reading into linq since its one of the, if not the most, powerful aspect of .Net/C# compared to Java/Other languages.

Comment: Thank you, Ill have a bash at it now, could you possibly recommend anything to read on Linq?

Comment: yea sure, i find this to be useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C

Comment: also, you might want to look into linq to sql, since you seem to use entity framework? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff728653.aspx

Comment: the query i've shown in my answer basically gives you all items where the orderid is the same as the one you want.

Comment: also, if you are curios about what linq does internally (or what it probably does) check out jon skeets blog: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction/ , he also has other interesting posts, that will help you understand c#

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your class structure, Here is simple code example which simply provides you the collection of OrderDetails object for an orderId and username:

```
   var orderDetails = Orders.Select(x => x.OrderId = orderId && x.username="yourusename");
```

Now iterate through these items using foreach.